# Using a level triggered latch as a negative edge trigger for negative logic

Tags: ram, timing, latching

I am a (relatively) new hobbyist and I am working on a project that uses an old video chip (v9938.) The chip is designed to use old DRAM, with a multiplexed 8 bit address bus, and *RAS and *CAS signals.  These chips are both very inconvenient and also difficult to find, so I am replacing them with a single SRAM chip, which has standard parallel address lines.

To accomplish this, I am going to latch the 8 address bits on *RAS to use as the upper 8 bits of the 16 bit address.  The most obvious way to do this is to use an inverter on *RAS and a positive edge trigger octal D flip flop to latch on the falling edge of *RAS

However, is there any issue using a positive level triggered latch using the *RAS line as the latch.  To me this seems like it would work as a negative edge triggered latch, getting a final latched value when *RAS goes low.  The timing diagram shows the address is stable at least 50ns before *RAS falls:

[image: Timing Diagram]
[image: Timing Values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positive level-triggered latch is perfectly fine and perhaps the best solution.

The challenge I think is emulating VRAM, which uses an auto-increment burst address mode and has a separate video read port.

Comment: I don’t think the old 4116 drams had auto-increment magic.

Comment: Notice the heading on the timing diagram: ‘VRAM’. That would not be a 4116…

Comment: The 9938 is the video chip for MSX computers. Find the Yamaha data sheet and the only dram feature I could find is page mode where just the column addr is strobed in. VRAM in this instance is ‘video ram’ as opposed to specific video dram devices that had serial addr access etc.